# How to make a responsive menu in bootstrap without the collapse option?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, togglebutton

I want to make a bootstrap responsive menu without the collapse option. So in responsive side the menu will show up as it was collapsed, so without clicking the menu-toggle. Here is the menu!

```
<section id="menuja2"><!-- Menuja 2-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default menu2">
<div class="container">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu2" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu2">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">Roses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lavendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carnations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Daises</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Peonies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Irises</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Baksets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Arrangements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sunflowers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

</section><!-- Fund Menuja 2 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `in` class to `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu2">`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="menu2">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">Roses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lavendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carnations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Daises</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Peonies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Irises</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Baksets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Arrangements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sunflowers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sr5z9mag/1/

You can then remove the button, or do whatever you like with it...

Another fiddle without the `button` element: https://jsfiddle.net/sr5z9mag/2/

Comment: No problem @MrVampo, please upvote and accept answers that help you as they will help others in the future :-)